# select textbox with RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

Start RSelenium

```
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
pJS <- phantom()
Sys.sleep(5) # give the binary a moment
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
remDr$open()
```

Go to the site and wait a bit

```
remDr$navigate("http://ideal-scope.com/online-holloway-cut-adviser/")
Sys.sleep(5)
```

now when I try to find element on the text boxes

```
  depthElem <- remDr$findElements("name","depth_textbox")
  tableElem <- remDr$findElements("name","table_textbox")
  crownElem <- remDr$findElements("name","crown_textbox")
  pavilionElem <- remDr$findElements("name","pavilion_textbox")
```

...just gives me a bunch of objects that are `list()`

If I do `findElement` instead of `findElements` I get

```
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
 Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

How can I select these textboxes? Why can't I select them by searching name?

Comment: The `findElements` method returns an empty list when no elements are present. The page has the content you require in an iframe. You will need to switch to the iframe first before you can search for the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The findElements method returns an empty list when no elements are present. The page has the content you require in an iframe. You will need to switch to the iframe first before you can search for the elements:

```
remDr$navigate("http://ideal-scope.com/online-holloway-cut-adviser/")
# get iframes
webElems <- remDr$findElements("css", "iframe")
# there is only one
remDr$switchToFrame(webElems[[1]])

depthElem <- remDr$findElement("name","depth_textbox")
# > depthElem$getElementAttribute("name")
# [[1]]
# [1] "depth_textbox"
remDr$findElement("name","table_textbox")
crownElem <- remDr$findElement("name","crown_textbox")
pavilionElem <- remDr$findElement("name","pavilion_textbox")
```